# querySelectorAll selects more than one element

Tags: javascript

```js
const ratingElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ratings");

ratingElements.forEach((ratingElement) => {
    ratingElement.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.innerText || event.target.parentNode.innerText); // || means "OR"
        event.target.classList.add("active") 
        event.target.parentNode.classList.add("active")
    });
});
```

```css
.ratings__container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
  gap: 5px;
}

.ratings {
  min-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

.ratings:hover, .active{
  background: darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: aliceblue;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
    <h1 class="heading">Feedback UI</h1>
    <div class="ratings__container" id="ratings__container">
        <div class="ratings" aria-label="unhappy">
            <img src="unhappy.svg" alt="Unhappy" class="emoji-icon">
                <small>Unhappy</small>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings" aria-label="neutral">
            <img src="neutral.svg" alt="Neutral" class="emoji-icon">
                <small>Neutral</small>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings" aria-label="happy">
            <img src="happy-icon.svg" alt="Happy" class="emoji-icon">
                <small>Happy</small>

            </div>
    </div>
        <button class="btn">
            Send Review
        </button>
</div>
```

it should likely to be this[image: when clicked]

but it is like
[image: this happens]

Comment: When I test clicking your elements, only the one I click is being assigned the updated class.  Can you include the styling in the example and indicate specifically what you're observing?

Comment: Are you sure it's `.querySelectorAll` which is the problem? All it does is add a listener to each element. Surely that's what you want - each element to do something when clicked. As opposed to only one of them.

Comment: only the one I click gets the class as well, there is no logic to remove the class when selecting a different element tho

Comment: CSS:
`.ratings__container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 0;
    gap: 5px;
}

.ratings {
    min-width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

.ratings:hover,
.active{
    background: darkseagreen;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: aliceblue;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}` @David

Comment: @Alok: And in what way is this code not working as expected?  Elaborate on the specific test you are performing and the specific unexpected result you are seeing.  The code shown in the question is working as expected.

Comment: @David : it adds active everywhere <div class="ratings__container active" id="ratings__container">
            <div class="ratings" aria-label="unhappy">
                
            <div class="ratings active" aria-label="neutral">
                <img src="neutral.svg" alt="Neutral" class="emoji-icon active">
                <small class="active">Neutral</small>
            </div>
            
        </div>

Comment: The behavior seems intermittent for me.

Comment: @David I think what he is trying to do is add green background to only emoji part but whole background is getting green color . If you look carefully you can see green color applying to background also and one more  problem here is when you click on other emoji both of them turns green.

Answer (score 0):

You were adding active class to the parent div which is why whole div is turning green when you click on one emoji. One more thing was , when you click on one emoji then click on other both of them were  getting green background color. Here is the solution .

```js
const ratingElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ratings");
const images= document.getElementsByClassName("emoji-icon");
ratingElements.forEach((ratingElement) => {
    ratingElement.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
     for(image of images){
    image.classList.remove("active");
    }
    
    
        event.target.classList.add("active") 
       
    });
});
```

```css
.ratings__container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
  gap: 5px;
  background-color:aqua;
}

img
{
width:100px;
}

.ratings {
  min-width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

.ratings:hover, .active{
  background: darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: aliceblue;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
    <h1 class="heading">Feedback UI</h1>
    <div class="ratings__container" id="ratings__container">
        <div class="ratings" aria-label="unhappy">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Happy_Emoji_Icon_5c9b7b25-b215-4457-922d-fef519a08b06_large.png?v=1571606090 alt="Unhappy" class="emoji-icon">
                <small>Unhappy</small>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings" aria-label="neutral">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Happy_Emoji_Icon_5c9b7b25-b215-4457-922d-fef519a08b06_large.png?v=1571606090" alt="Neutral" class="emoji-icon">
                <small>Neutral</small>
        </div>
        <div class="ratings" aria-label="happy">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Happy_Emoji_Icon_5c9b7b25-b215-4457-922d-fef519a08b06_large.png?v=1571606090" alt="Happy" class="emoji-icon">
                <small>Happy</small>

            </div>
    </div>
        <button class="btn">
            Send Review
        </button>
</div>
```

remove  `event.target.parentNode.classList.add("active")` . Then select images using `getElementsByClassName()`(or whichever method you prefer) then remove class active for all of them . Then add class active to only one emoji .